# Handle spaces in URL using httr package

Tags: r, json, http, url

I'd like to know how to have `GET` from the `httr` package automatically handle parameter values that have a space in them.

When I paste this in my browser:

```
http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api/api_GET/?key=MYAPIKEY&commodity_desc=AG LAND&short_desc=AG LAND, IRRIGATED - ACRES&short_desc=AG LAND - ACRES&year__GE=2015&state_alpha=NC
```

the spaces are replaced with %20 and the data is obtained from the site. This is the url that the browser returns:

```
https://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api/api_GET/?key=MYAPIKEY&commodity_desc=AG%20LAND&short_desc=AG%20LAND,%20IRRIGATED%20-%20ACRES&short_desc=AG%20LAND%20-%20ACRES&year__GE=2015&state_alpha=NC
```

The parameters such as "AG LAND" in the object `my_commodity_desc` and "AG LAND, IRRIGATED - ACRES" in `my_short_desc1` have spaces in them and I think that's the issue.

This is the code I'm running to get data from http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov:

```
# url
nass_url <- "http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov"
# commodity description of interest
my_commodity_desc <- "AG LAND"

# short description of interest (i.e., 'data item' on NASS Quick Stats website)
my_short_desc1 <- "AG LAND, IRRIGATED - ACRES"
my_short_desc2 <- "AG LAND - ACRES"

# query start year
my_year <- "2015"

# state of interest
my_state <- "NC"

# final path string
path_nc_irrig_land <- paste0("api/api_GET/?key=", NASS_API_KEY,
                             "&commodity_desc=", my_commodity_desc,
                             "&short_desc=", my_short_desc1,
                             "&short_desc=", my_short_desc2,
                             "&year__GE=", my_year,
                             "&state_alpha=", my_state)
# Run the query
raw_result_nc_irrig_land <- GET(url = nass_url, path = path_nc_irrig_land)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use base R's `URLencode` (from package `utils`), which does much the same thing that your browser does:

```r
URLencode(path_nc_irrig_land)
#> [1] "api/api_GET/?key=myAPIKey&commodity_desc=AG%20LAND&short_desc=AG%20LAND,%20IRRIGATED%20-%20ACRES&short_desc=AG%20LAND%20-%20ACRES&year__GE=2015&state_alpha=NC"
```

Answer (score 0):

`httr::GET()` does this for you via the `query` argument:

```
query <- list(key=NASS_API_KEY,
              commodity_desc=my_commodity_desc,
              short_desc=my_short_desc1,
              etc...)
response <- GET(url = nass_url, path = "api/api_GET", query = query)
```

You can see the URL that is going to be effectively used with:

```
modify_url(url = nass_url, path = "api/api_GET", query = query)
```